# Storing and reading Names and Addresses, and creating new instances for each entry

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary

So, I created a class called "Book" with the intention of storing names and addresses.

However, I am a little bit lost with what to do next.

I want to have the program read names and addresses from a file and create a new instance of the "Book" class for each new entry. I know one way of doing this is using NSArchiver, but is there another method?

Comment: How will the names and addresses get into the file?

Comment: I was thinking of using NSURL and stringWithContentsOfURL, and using for loops to read the names and addresses based the delimiters such as commas...etc. However, I'm still having problems with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break the process down a bit further. Start with the reading process. Pick the system that you are most familiar with the load the data. Figure out how to read until you have enough data for one object, then create a copy of that object and fill it with the data. Repeat until your data is all used up.

You can simplify it even further for your own experience; make a dummy reader which simply returns hard coded data for 2 or 3 entries. use that the populate the Book class. You can even keep that for a unit test which you an use to test the behavior of your class over time, so that you can see what it does without worrying about the reading logic.